# Why am I getting this output in from sort?

Tags: sort

I'm using the following chain of commands to sort a [FASTQ file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format):

```
cat reads.fq | paste - - - - | sort -k1,1 -S 3G | tr '\t' '\n' > sorted_reads.fq
```

The FASTQ file is separated into groups for four line first of which is the id we want to sort on.

But in the output I see this pattern:

```
@ERR894725.10000000/1
AGAAAAAGAAAAATTGTTTCCTGTTATATCCATTTCCTTTAATATAGTTTACAAATTGTGCATTTCAACAGCAGCACTCTGTCCATATGTCTAGCAGACTCCTTAACACACTGTGCTACAACTTCT
+
<B<<B<<<B<<<<<<<B<B<BB<BB<<<<<BB<BB<BB<B<B0<<<<BBB<<BBB<B<B<BB<<B<BB<B<BB0BB<B<B<<<<<<BB<B<BB<BB<B<BBBBBBB0B<B<BBB<B0B<BB<<07<
@ERR894725.100000002/1
AGATAGAGTCTTGCTCTGTCACCCAGCCTGGAGTGCAACGGTGCTATCTCTACTAACTGCAACCTCCGCCCCCCAGGTTCAAGCGATTCTCCTGCCTCAGCCTCCTGAGCAGCTGGGACTACAGTG
+
<<<<<BB<<<B<<BB<B<B<B<BBBBBBB<BBBB<BBB<7BB<BB<<<B<B<<B<B<B<BBB<<B<B7BBBBBBBBBBB<BBBB'B<B<BB<B<BBBBBBBBBBBBB<BBBBBBBBBB<BB<<<<<
@ERR894725.100000002/2
TGTACAGAAAGTATCTGTTTTATTAATTCAACACTGTAAACATTTGCCATGTCTTAAAGTTCAAGTCTCTGTAACCTCCTGAGGTCAGGAGTTTGACATCAGCCTGACCAACATGGTGAAACCCTG
+
<<<<<B<BB<<<<<<B<<<<<<<<<<<<<B<<B<B<<<<<<B<<<<B<B<<<<B<<<<<<<<<<<B<B<B<B<B<BB<BB<BBBB<BBBBBBBB<B<B<<BBBBB<B<BBB<BBBBBBBBB<<<<<
@ERR894725.10000000/2
CTACATAATTTCCCTTACTGGACTAGCTTTTTTTCGGTGCTATTTTAAAATATGTTTAATTCTCCAACTGCTTAGAAGTCTTTTTAGATATTTTGCTGGGTGCAATAGCACACTTTATATCTATAT
+
7B<<B<<<<<B<<<B<<<B<<B<B<<BB<<<<<<<7<B<BB<<<<<<B<<<<<<B<<<<<<<<<<BB<B0<B0<0BBBB<BBBBB<<<<<<BBB<BB<<BB<BBB<BBB0<B<BBBBBBBBB<<7<
@ERR894725.100000003/1
AAAGAGAGCCCGCATTGCCAAGTCAATCCTAAGCCAAAAGAACAAAGCTGGAGGCATCACGCTACCTGACTTCAAATTATACTACAAGGCTACAGTAACCAAAACAGCATGGTACTGGTACCAAAA
+
<<<<B<B<<<<7BB<<<BBBBBB<BB<<BB<BBBBBBBBBBB<BBBBBB<BBBBBB<<B<7B<<<BB<B<BB<BBB<B<<<<B<<BB<BBBB<BBB<B<BBBBB<BBBBBBBBB<BBBBB<B<<<B
@ERR894725.100000003/2
AAATTTTCTCCCATTCTGTAGGTTGCCTGTTCACTCTGATGGTAGTTTCTTTTGCTGTGCAGAAGCTCTTTAGTTTAATTAGAACCCATTTGTCAATTTTGGCTTTTGTTGCCATTGCTTTTGGTG
+
<<<<<<<<B<<<B<<<B<<<<<<<<B<B<<<<B<B<B<B<<<<<B<<<<B<<<<BB<<<BB<<<BBB<B<B<BBBB<B<B<BBB<BBB<BB<B<B<<BBB<BBB<BBBBB<B<0BBBBBBBB<<70
```

Why is there a gap between the `@ERR894725.10000000/1` group and the `@ERR894725.10000000/2` one? The ASCII code for `/` is smaller than that of any number so I don't see why `@ERR894725.100000002/1` takes precedence over `@ERR894725.10000000/2`.

I see the same pattern across the entire file. There is a gap between `@ERR894725.10000001/1` and `@ERR894725.10000001/1` filled by `@ERR894725.100000012/1` and `@ERR894725.100000012/1` and so on.

Any explanation for why this is happening and ways to avoid it is appreciated.

** Update: The actual data is quite large (1TB+) and can't be provided in it's entirety. I tried sorting the example above using the same commands again and it gives a correct result. I'll try resorting the already sorted complete output to see if it fixes things. Still weird why this has happened in first place.

Comment: Hard to say why you're seeing the given output with those commands without seeing the input.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `tr` command?

Comment: Try to post a minimal failing example. i.e. remove all the extra characters, and simplify your input file to contain only the parts that fail. It will be much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Just a hunch: I wonder if your input file uses a different line terminator than the utilities expect. Do you get the same results if you use `tr -s '\r' '\n' < reads.fq` (to convert all linebreaks to Unix style) instead of `cat reads.fq`?

Comment: It's hard when your output's been split into 4 (?) lines after the sort. Can you show intermediate input & output, in order to focus on the problem?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's split into 4 lines because that's how a FASTQ file is. The `paste` command collapses every four lines into one so that they can be sorted.

Comment: Something is splitting the output after the sort but before you see it, so the shell pipeline you're debugging is different from what's in your question. Copy/pasting your output and running `paste - - - - |  sort -k1,1 -S 3G | cut -f2` against it gives the order you asked for. There is something missing from your question.

Comment: If this is GNU sort, you can use `--debug` to see exactly what it's sorting on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Locale locale locale

You get unexpected results because your default locale is something other than `C` or `C.UTF-8`.

`sort` sorts in the order of byte values only in the C locale; in other locales `sort` sorts in the mysterious order defined by well-intentioned souls in the locale definition files.

Compare:

```
$ <<< $'@ERR894725.10000000/1\t1\n@ERR894725.100000002/1\t2\n@ERR894725.100000002/2\t3\n@ERR894725.10000000/2\t4' \
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort -s -k1.1
@ERR894725.10000000/1   1
@ERR894725.100000002/1  2
@ERR894725.100000002/2  3
@ERR894725.10000000/2   4

$ <<< $'@ERR894725.10000000/1\t1\n@ERR894725.100000002/1\t2\n@ERR894725.100000002/2\t3\n@ERR894725.10000000/2\t4' \
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort -s -k1.1
@ERR894725.10000000/1   1
@ERR894725.10000000/2   4
@ERR894725.100000002/1  2
@ERR894725.100000002/2  3
```

If you value consistency, always say `LC_ALL=C sort` (or `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 sort`, or in general `LC_ALL=`<your-preferred-locale> `sort`) and never just `sort`.

The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sort.1.html) has this to say:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. Set `LC_ALL=C` to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems like it could be the source of the problem. I'll need to re-sort the file which might take a day or two and update the result.

Comment: So I ran `LC_ALL=C cat reads.fq | paste - - - - | sort -k1,1 -S 3G | tr '\t' '\n' > sorted_reads.fq` and the result is the same. Can it be due to setting the locale not immediately before calling `sort`?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C sort`. Or `export LC_ALL=C` and then `< reads.fq paste - - - - | sort`. But `LC_ALL=C cat | paste | sort ` does *not* set `LC_ALL` for `sort`. (Explanation: `LC_ALL` is an environment variable. You can either set such a variable as a separate command and then it will take effect in all subsequent commands, or you can set it temporarily for just *one* command.)

Comment: I see. I had assumed `LC_ALL=C <command>` is the equivalent of `export LC_ALL=C; <command>` .

Comment: It is, but it takes effect only for the <command>; and it must be a "simple command", so in `LC_ALL=C cat | paste - - - - | sort` it takes effect for `cat` but not for `paste` or `sort`.

Comment: Yeah that was my misunderstanding. It seems to work now.